# How to round final result query

Tags: mysql

**Hi**, my **MYSQL** data base contains the table called `new-sell` with the following columns `registeredDay` and `productFinalPrice` they show **total** **registered** purchase **value** and the **date** that entry was **made**.

`|=====================================|
 |  productFinalPrice | registeredDay  |
 |=====================================|
 |     600,00 | 2017-09-19 18:45:16    |
 |     435,50 | 2017-09-18 18:45:16    |
 |     817,60 | 2017-09-17 18:45:16    |
 |     176,00 | 2017-09-16 18:45:16    |
 |     600,00 | 2017-09-15 18:45:16    |
 |     600,00 | 2017-09-14 18:45:16    |
 |     600,00 | 2017-09-13 18:45:16    |
 |     842,10 | 2017-09-20 18:45:16    |
 |     415,20 | 2017-09-21 18:45:16    |
 |     230,45 | 2017-09-22 18:45:16    |
 |     400,00 | 2017-09-20 18:45:16    |
 |     375,00 | 2017-09-20 18:45:16    |
 =======================================`

I'm **using** this **MySQL command** to calculate the **average** earnings compared to **yesterday** and before **yesterday**.

```
SELECT PRICE_T / (PRICE_T2-PRICE_T) * 100 AS PERC
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN PRICE_I2 ELSE 0 END) AS PRICE_T
           , SUM(PRICE_I2) AS PRICE_T2
      FROM (SELECT CAST(registeredDay AS DATE) AS DDATE
            , SUM(productFinalPrice) AS PRICE_I2
            , @RN:=@RN+1 AS RN
            FROM new_sell 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0) X
            WHERE registeredDay BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 day) AND CURDATE()
            GROUP BY CAST(registeredDay AS DATE)
            ORDER BY CAST(registeredDay AS DATE)
           ) B
    ) C;
```

**This is the end result.**
`37,1057513914657`

However i **wanted** to **round** this **final** value through `ROUND()` how **could** i **add** this **command** to the **above query**?

Thanks for helping me :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`round()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function directly in your select.

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(PRICE_T / (PRICE_T2-PRICE_T) * 100) AS PERC
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN PRICE_I2 ELSE 0 END) AS PRICE_T
           , SUM(PRICE_I2) AS PRICE_T2
      FROM (SELECT CAST(registeredDay AS DATE) AS DDATE
            , SUM(productFinalPrice) AS PRICE_I2
            , @RN:=@RN+1 AS RN
            FROM new_sell 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0) X
            WHERE registeredDay BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 day) AND CURDATE()
            GROUP BY CAST(registeredDay AS DATE)
            ORDER BY CAST(registeredDay AS DATE)
           ) B
    ) C;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use sum inside round like -
SELECT ROUND(column_name,decimals) FROM table_name;